# Android Eclipse DDMS > Heap > Cause GC greyed out

Tags: android, memory, garbage-collection, heap-memory, ddms

I'm unable to click the Cause GC button in the Heap tab under the DDMS Perspective in Eclipse because it is greyed out.

I'm using ADT v22 (the Eclipse/Android/ADT package) on OS X. Device I'm using is an S3.

Steps followed:
1. Deployed app from Eclipse
2. Selected process in DDMS
3. Click Heap Update button
4. Opened Heap tab but Cause GC is greyed out. I'm guessing this is because no data has populated the heap tab (no client to select and no objects in the list).

Does anyone know what might be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try running 'adb kill-server' and 'adb start-server' inside '/platform-tools/'.
Check this out for help http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. If I click DDMS in Eclipse, Gause GC is grayed out and cannot be performed. However, DDMS is also shipped in the tools/ directory of the Android SDK. Everything is OK if I type ddms (or ./ddms on Mac/Linux) from the tools/ directory.